# Variable updating 4 times per function call

Tags: java, android

I have the following code and the problem is that the variable `numbOfBlinks` is incremented by four each time. I'm assuming that the onUpdate method is being called 4 times per second. My goal is to count the number of times a user blinks. I'm not sure the best way to do it.

```
 @Override
       public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
           mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
           mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
           if (flag == 0) {
               eye_tracking(face);
           }

       }

      
       private void eye_tracking(Face face) {
           float leftEye = face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability();
           float rightEye = face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability();

           if (leftEye > THRESHOLD && rightEye > THRESHOLD) {
               state_i = 0;
               firstTime = true;
               firstTimeSMS = true;

              Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Open Eyes Detected");

           } else {

               if (state_i == 0) {
                   lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                   lastLowToHighStateSMS = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

               }

               if (firstTime && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLowToHighState > alarmTime) {

                   // Used to prevent the function from continuously firing
                   lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                   firstTime = false;
                   alert_box();
                   flag = 1;
               }
               if (firstTimeSMS && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLowToHighStateSMS > smsTime) {
                   try {
                       sendSMS();
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                   lastLowToHighStateSMS = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                   firstTimeSMS = false;
               }
               numbOfBlinks++;
               state_i = 1;
               Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate: Closed Eyes Detected");
           }
       }
```

**EDIT after Alexander M code**

[image]

```
 @Override
        public void onUpdate(FaceDetector.Detections<Face> detectionResults, Face face) {
            mOverlay.add(mFaceGraphic);
            mFaceGraphic.updateFace(face);
            if (flag == 0) {
                eye_tracking(face);
            }

        }

    
        private void onEyesClosed() {
            eyesClosed = true;
        }

        private void onEyesOpened() {
            if (eyesClosed) {
                numbOfBlinks++;
                Log.i(TAG,"numb of blinks"+ numbOfBlinks);
            }
            eyesClosed = false;
        }

        private void eye_tracking(Face face) {
            float leftEye = face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability();
            float rightEye = face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability();

            if (leftEye > THRESHOLD && rightEye > THRESHOLD) {
                state_i = 0;
                firstTime = true;
                firstTimeSMS = true;
                onEyesOpened();


                //Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Open Eyes Detected");

            } else {

                onEyesClosed();
                if (state_i == 0) {
                    lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    lastLowToHighStateSMS = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                }

                if (firstTime && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLowToHighState > alarmTime) {

                    // Used to prevent the function from continuously firing
                    lastLowToHighState = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    firstTime = false;
                    alert_box();
                    flag = 1;
                }
                if (firstTimeSMS && SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastLowToHighStateSMS > smsTime) {
                    try {
                        sendSMS();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    lastLowToHighStateSMS = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    firstTimeSMS = false;
                }
                numbOfBlinks++;
                state_i = 1;
                //Log.d(TAG, "onUpdate: Closed Eyes Detected");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you already have a way to detect opened and closed eyes. Provided that, I'd recommend you to add two methods to your class: `onEyesClosed()` and `onEyesOpened()`. Call them from your `eye_tracking(Face face)` method (both methods can be called many times in a row, that doesn't matter). Now, let's build "blink detection logic" based on there two methods:

```
private boolean eyesClosed;
private int numbOfBlinks;

private void onEyesClosed() {
    eyesClosed = true;
}

private void onEyesOpened() {
    if (eyesClosed) {
        numbOfBlinks++;
    }
    eyesClosed = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank for for you answer, I have added a snippet of my log in my original post. As you can see the number of blinks is being incremented by five each time.

Comment: @ReeceG don't forget to remove `numbOfBlinks++;` from other places ;)